# Provide a paraphrase for the following quotation from “Where are Humans’ Close Cousins?”

Tags: meaning

What does this quote mean?

“For the disappearance of our close relatives, we should consider another potential culprit: our ancestors.”

Comment: The way I understand it: We should consider modern human ancestors as one of the possible reasons other ancestral hominid relatives disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

my paraphrase:

> Human Ancestors killed all the closely related species off before the present day.

Answer (score 0):

I could paraphrase this as:

> When thinking about the disappearance of our closest genetic relatives, we need to consider that early humans may have killed them off.

Comment: That's longer than the original!

Comment: @Oldcat It doesn't have to be shorter, just clearer in meaning.  [Definition of paraphrase](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paraphrase)